# How to fill up line with delimiters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a cell array A, which I wish to print as a table. The first columns and first row are headers. For example I have

```
 A:
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
 A:
 1   ||2    |3
 -------------
 4   ||5    |6
 7   ||8    |9
```

The vertical bars are not problematic. I just dont know how to print out the horizontal line. It should be more flexible then just `disp('-------')`. It should resize depending on how big my strings in my cells are.

So far I only implemented the ugly way which just displays a static string '-----'.

```
function [] = dispTable(table)
basicStr = '%s\t| ';
fmt = strcat('%s\t||',repmat(basicStr,1,size(table,2)-1),'\n');
lineHeader = '------';
%print first line as header:
fprintf(1,fmt,table{1,:});
disp(lineHeader);
fprintf(1,fmt,table{2:end,:});
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is going to be tough since you're using tabs and the width of a tab in spaces varies from machine to machine. I would recommend using `sprintf` with fixed width fields instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to reliably be able to compute the width of a field since you are using tabs whose width can vary from machine to machine. Also if you're trying to display something in a tabular structure, it's best to avoid tabs just in case two values are different by more than 8 characters which would lead to the columns not lining up.

Rather than using tabs, I would use fixed-width fields for your data, then you know exactly how many `-` characters to use.

```
% Construct a format string using fixed-width fonts
% NOTE: You could compute the needed width dynamically based on input
format = ['%-4s||', repmat('%-4s|', 1, size(table, 2) - 1)];

% Replace the last | with a newline
format(end) = char(10);

% You can compute how many hypens you need to span your data
h_line = [repmat('-', [1, 5 * size(table, 2)]), 10];

% Now print the result
fprintf(format, table{1,:})
fprintf(h_line)
fprintf(format, table{2:end,:})

%    1   ||2   |3
%    ---------------
%    4   ||7   |5
%    8   ||6   |9
```

Comment: Wow Thank you. That was fast! Well in my special case a constant width is suffucient. But I will leave this question open for some time just in case somebody knows a method with the tabs appoach.

Comment: @VietTran You also want to avoid tabs just in case two of your values in a column differ by more than the tab width. This would cause the columns to not line up any more. Fixed-width fields are a better approach for displays like this.

Comment: So you would recommend to determine the maximum width length first and then use the fixed-width approach?

Comment: @VietTran I would determine the amount of padding you want to the right, then for each column compute the maximum width + the padding and use that as the fixed width for that column.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now think your approach is the way to go. Tabs are just messy to deal with. As you stated there are problems if the columns differ more than the tab width. So I accepted the awnser :)